# How to use the uniswap subgraph to search the pools of a token that you are deploying to the sepolia testnet?

Tags: uniswap, cpp-ethereum

How to use the uniswap subgraph to search the pools of a token that you are deploying to the sepolia testnet?
I have already tried with both including georli but it always returns an empty array.

url: https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3